# jqGrid get all ids

Tags: jqgrid

I've noticed a small bug with jqgrid that if you have virtual scrolling set to 1 and try and try to select all rows it doesn't actually select them all meaning when you call

```
$("#file-grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
```

to get all selected row data it doesn't actually get all the data. I was wondering if there was a method to get all row ids, selected or not using jqgrid.

Comment: I take it that `getDataIDs` would exhibit the same problem, of only returning some if the ID's?

Comment: Yup it only works for visible rows, not all of them

Answer (score 11):

Use the following if you're not using pagination:

```
var allRowsOnCurrentPage = $('#file-grid').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
```

Comment: -1 The question specifically asked how to get all rows; not just the ones that are visible. This only retrieves visible rows.

Answer (score 4):

could you try getRowData() with no parameters - it should return all of the rows in the grid:

```
var allRowsInGrid = $('#file-grid').jqGrid('getRowData');
```

I got this from the jqGrid wiki:

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods

Comment: This returns not only IDs, but all columns of each row.

Comment: Also, this only returns data from the current page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
 var grid = jQuery("#mylist");
 var ids = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');

 for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    var rowId = ids[i];
 }
```